# Backward chaining in artificial intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chaining

I need to understand the Backward chaining concept in expert systems (artificial intelligence) without using formal logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the rule

```
it_rains -> street_is_wet
```

which means that if it is raining the street is wet.
Then backward chaining means that if you want to know if the street is wet you have to check if it is raining. So you go backwards through the rule.

Comment: <p>Can you give me a **bold**complete example" please.</p>

Comment: I am not shure what you mean but I try to be more precise. The expert system should tell you something about a fact of its topic. So you want to know if something holds. The system uses logic implications like rules I showed above. There could be more rules, e.g. `dark_clouds_at_the_sky and high_pressure -> it_rains`. There also facts in the systems. That could be sensor data or common sense facts like "the sky is blue". You would then ask the system "Is the street wet?". Because of the first rule it checks if `it_rains` holds.

Comment: Because of the second rule it has to check if `dark_clouds_at_the_sky and high_pressure` holds. Because backwards chaining means you go backwards through the rules. If in the system this two facts are then true it can conclude due to the rules and the facts that `street_is_wet` holds and returns `true`. Otherwise, it would return `false`. Such a question is often called goal because it is the goal of the system to tell you if it is true. So backward chaining means starting with the goal and go backwards through the chained rules until the system reaches facts which are true or false.

Comment: Was this example complete enough?

Comment: Yes, But because I'm not good in English I spend time to understand :D

Comment: Thank you very much